# MLAB / Heroku - mongorestore undefined

Tags: database, mongodb, shell, heroku, mlab

According to the Mlab & MongoDb documentation, inserting an existing local BSON collection into a new cloud collection should be fairly straight forward.

Import collection
`mongorestore -h <host_url> -d <db_name> -u <user> -p <password> <input .bson file>`

https://www.mlab.com/databases/your_db_name#tools

I've successfully connected to the mongo shell, but:

a) I'm unable to verify the OS used per https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/import/#check-your-environment - `ls` returns `[native code]`

b) Running the command for `mongorestore` returns a lot of `missing ; before statement` SyntaxErrors (which I am able to fix despite the strangeness)

c) Running the command returns `mongorestore is not defined`

Depressingly, i'll have to spin up an endpoint in the cloud and post all my docs from local to cloud via that method.

However if anyone knows what the issue here is? Why would `mongorestore` (and incidentally `mongoimport`) not be available?

Comment: Which mongodb version did you download?

Comment: It was the pre-installed version with mlab / heroku so no additional config done by myself. Would have assumed this would be basic functionality out of the box...

Comment: I'm checking to see if you have the mongorestore/import binaries in your bin mongodb bin folder. That way I can help you see why the command is not defined.

Comment: This is in the cloud not locally and I'm unable to run anything in the CLI as per point a). I can't verify anything on the system at all. That is probably the bigger issue with this in all honesty...